# time dependent krylov time evolution with nested for loop in python too slow

Tags: python, performance, nested-loops

I have implemented a correlation function evaluated at two time points Nt1 and Nt2 for a quantum system. In the end we have to integrate over all possible Nt1 and Nt2 so we have to calculate the correlation function for all possible Nt1, Nt2 in 0,..., Nt_max. The calculation is done one hpc with 64 processors. The calculation for the different Nt1 is parallelized, with a bash routine submitting the jobs to one of the processors. One job comprises the following routine in order to calculate the k dependent correlation function:

```
def propagater(Nt1, Nt_max, phi, dim_krylov):

    # phi is the ground state of the system
    v1 = phi
    G_t2_k = np.zeros((Nt_max, len(k_all)), dtype=complex)

    for Ntr in range(Nt1):
        # create Ntr dependent Hamiltonian 1
        H_spin = make_H_spin(Ntr)
        # get eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and lanczos vectors with a lanczos method
        E_spin, V_spin, Q_T_spin = lanczos_full(H_spin, v1, dim_krylov)
        # apply time propagation for timestep dt: v1 = e^(-ij*H_spin*dt)*v1
        v1 = expm_lanczos(E_spin, V_spin, Q_T_spin, a=-1j * dt)

    # manipulate state, that implies as basis change
    v2 = createHole(v1)

    # propagation for all possible Nt2
    for Nt2 in range(Nt_max):
        v3 = v2
        # propagate v3 to t2
        # if t2<t1 we have to propagate backward in time, hence the np.sign
        for Ntr in range(np.abs(Nt2 - Nt1)):
            Ntime = Nt1 + np.sign(Nt2 - Nt1) * Ntr
            # create Ntr dependent Hamiltonian 2
            H_tJ = make_H_tJ(Ntime)
            E_tJ, V_tJ, Q_T = lanczos_full(H_tJ, v3, dim_krylov)
            v3 = expm_lanczos(E_tJ, V_tJ, Q_T, a=-np.sign(Nt2 - Nt1) * 1j * dt)

        # propagate <phi| to t2 (corresponds to v3 backward in time)
        v4 = phi
        for Ntr in range(Nt2):
            H_spin = make_H_spin(Ntr)
            E_spin, V_spin, Q_T_spin = lanczos_full(H_spin, v4, dim_krylov)
            v4 = expm_lanczos(E_spin, V_spin, Q_T_spin, a=-1j * dt)

        # now store the expectation value
        file = open("prop_" + str(Nt1) + "_bash.txt", "a")
        # manipulation of state implies a k dependence as well
        for k_id, k in enumerate(k_all):
            phi_pj = createHole(v4)
            G_t2_k_r = np.real(np.vdot(phi_pj, v3))
            G_t2_k_im = np.imag(np.vdot(phi_pj, v3))
            file.write(str(G_t2_k_r) + "\t" + str(G_t2_k_im) + "\t")
            G_t2_k[Nt2, k_id] = np.vdot(phi_pj, v3)
        file.write("\n")
        file.close()
```

I don't want to go into all of the details here, but I hope the general ideas became clear. However this code runs too slow in order to get some nice results. My question now is, how to speed it up. In general I think the most critical points are the loops (I know they are super slow in python). But I don't know how to vectorize them. I considered using numba, but unfortunately it does not support the csr format that I need to store the hamiltonian of my system. Another option would by pypy which I have not checked until now. I also considered to rewrite the code in C++ as I read that the loops there are faster, but I am also not sure of how big the advantage is. So all help is welcome!

Update: At least the hamiltonian creation (which was previous the bottleneck) is now done with numba. However its still the slowest function in the loop as one can see in the output of the [performance tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CYTt.png).

Comment: Loops in Python aren't slow per se, it's just that there are languages in which they are faster (and e.g. Numpy's vectorized operations exploit just that, doing the looping internally). Either way, have you profiled your code to see what the slowest bits are, and if those could be optimized? You can use Numba for just a function or two.

Comment: If you find, for instance, that your program spends a lot on time in `make_H_tJ`, `make_H_spin` or other pure functions, you could slap a `@functools.lru_cache()` on them so they're computed only once.

Comment: As above. If you are feeling more... adventurous, you should attempt to parallelize your computations. `for` loops are generally easy to parallelize, as you always know how many iterations there are. I recommend watching the open MIT lectures on parallelization - they provide a good introduction to the topic and help you understand why for example a C++ implementation is likely to outperform Python ones, especially when parallelizing stuff. The advantage is quite big, but it often requires hardcore expertise.

Comment: @AKX you are right, the creation of the Hamiltonians are by far the most time consuming. I think that could be a starting point for the optimization.

Comment: @KacperFloriański You mean also the parallelization of the Nt2 loop on a single processors would be advantageous?

Comment: @KacperFloriański OP mentions that this code is already parallelized "from outside".

Comment: Ah, my bad. I should've read through - pardon!

Comment: @AKX the lru_cache() did not work for "lanczos_full" and "expm_lanczos", it says: "unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'". But I don't understand why..

Comment: @AaronMüller Sure, it probably doesn't make sense to try caching something based on an array. But how about `make_H_tJ`, etc.? Are those heavy and cacheable?

Comment: @AKX So I set the flag `cache=True` in the numba jit decorater, so I think they are cached.

Comment: @AaronMüller That's only for caching the JIT bytecode (see https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/jit.html#cache). You can still `lru_cache` the numba'd function: `@lru_cache() @numba.jit(...) def ...():` (with suitable newlines)

Comment: @AKX I see, however I get `unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'` again.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to identify *where* the most time is spent, for this you can use a profiler. if a single function is too slow or is called too many times, This code starts from an O(n^2) so pay attention to how are used the function here.
For these cases, I wrote a package [perf_tool](https://pypi.org/project/perf-tool/) it can guide you in the right way.

if nothing striking comes out of the research, in general:

- Delegate to numpy all stuff that can be done vectorially like "Ntime = Nt1 + np.sign(Nt2 - Nt1) * Ntr".
- File write (I/0 bottleneck) can be done better using temporary data structures likes list. file.write('\t'.join(lot_of_values))
- all repetitive function calls can be memorized (as told by @AKX).
- lastly you can write some piece in C using [cython](https://cython.org/) or automatic compiler like [numba](http://numba.pydata.org/). For function with limited scope, these can help you to speed up a lot.

Comment: I checked my code with perf-tool and added the output to the question above.

Comment: About >90% of the time is spent into H_tJ creation and H_spin. I suppose the 2 function above. If these are out of the scope there is nothing more to do.